# Links based off slugs giving error

Tags: python, django

I have this link with url:

```
<a href="{% url 'listings:listing_detail' list.l_slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">See More</a>
```

It is directing it to this url pattern for my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from listings import views

app_name = 'listings'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UniversityListView.as_view(),name='universities'),
    url(r'^/(?P<name_initials>\w+)$',views.ListingView.as_view(),name='listing_detail'),
]
```

Here are the project url patterns to go along with it:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<u_slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.UniversityHomePageView.as_view(),name='university_homepage'),
    url(r'^(?P<u_slug>[-\w]+)/',include('listings.urls',namespace='listings')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

However I am getting this error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'listing_detail' with arguments '('stafford-apartments',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<u_slug>[-\\w]+)//(?P<name_initials>\\w+)$']
```

Django: 1.11

**Edit:**

Here is the detail view:

```
class ListingView(DetailView):
    model = Listing
    company = Company.objects.all()
    university = University.objects.all()
    context = {
            'listing':model,
            'company':company,
            'university':university,
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your listing_detail URL requires two arguments - u_slug and name_initials - but you are only providing one.

Comment: So would something like this work? `{% url 'listings:listing_detail' university.name_initials list.l_slug %}` and passing in the `university` model in the context?

Comment: Well, the other way round, and without the comma. But it's best to use keyword args to avoid confusion on ordering: `{% url 'listings:listing_detail' u_slug=list.l_slug name_initials=list.name_initials %}`.

Comment: I had to change a few things because the names were different but here's what I have: `{% url 'listings:listing_detail' l_slug=list.l_slug name_initials=name_initials %}` and it's still giving this error: `Reverse for 'listing_detail' with keyword arguments '{'l_slug': 'stafford-apartments', 'name_initials': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<name_initials>\\w+)//(?P<l_slug>[-\\w]+)$']`

Comment: That error is showing you that what you're passing as the second parameter is empty. You've used a standalone variable, are you sure there is one with that name in the context?

Comment: Well, firstly you are indeed not sending anything called `name_initials`; and secondly, that isn't at all how you manage context in a class-based view anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161125/discussion-between-garrett-and-daniel-roseman).